# TLS/SSL connection to Redis when using spring-data-redis

Tags: redis, spring-data, jedis, spring-data-redis

What is the recommended way to make a TLS/SSL connection to Redis sentinel using spring-data-redis and Jedis?

I'm using spring-data-redis 1.8.3.RELEASE with Jedis 2.9.0.

I understand that Redis does not provide direct support for TLS/SSL and instead recommends a secure proxy like spiped or stunnel. So lets assume I have setup the appropriate secure tunnels.

I can see that JedisConnectionFactory has a setUseSsl(boolean useSsl) method, but the value only seems to be used in createRedisPool() and not createRedisSentinelPool(), which leads me to think it is currently not possible with Redis sentinel.

Additionally, even when using standalone Redis and setting useSsl to true, there doesn't appear to be a way to set the SSLSocketFactory or parameters, so it will likely end up relying on the JVM's SSL system properties which is problematic if those aren't the SSL properties you wanted to use to connection to the secure tunnel.

Just trying to confirm if my above assumptions are correct, and if not then looking for pointers in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Did you get any way to do that